# Probability problem : How to find the number of try before reaching 1000 success with a given probability?

Tags: probability

I have a this probability problem (in a biological physics class)
'' We need to detect particles called fluorophores to reconstruct an image.
If we have a probability of p = 0.01 to detect each fluorophore and there are N = 1000 fluorophores to detect, how many n images must be put together in order to have a 95% probability of having seen all the fluorophores at least once (on an image of the n). ''

I don't understand how to start this problem... I don't even know which random variable distribution would be the best to even start. Do you have any hints for me ?

Thanks !

Comment: I don't think this is clear.  What does it mean to "detect" one of these things?  Are we testing one particle at a time?   Something else?  What does "on the image of the $n$" mean?  What is $n$?  I think if you describe the testing procedure clearly the solution will be evident.

Comment: @lulu let's assume we're testing one particle at a time. If we're presented with *one* particle, the probability that we're able to detect the kind fluorophore it is equals $1/100$. In this way, could we approach this with Markov chains on the state space $\{0,1,.\ldots,1000\}$?

Comment: How would you go about testing one particle at a time?  It makes more sense to me that you test all the particles at once, by shining a light on them, say (if that's what you do to detect them,) and on average $10$ of them are detected.  Then we want to know how many times to do the experiment so that the probability of having seen all of them at least once is $\geq0.95$.  I know nothing about this, though.  I had to Google  "fluorophore."

Comment: Markov chains?  I don't understand.  Describe your procedure in detail.  You have a list of particles...what exactly do you do?   Does the "$n$ images" bit have any meaning at all?

Comment: @lulu I'm going to assuming we're able to sample particles one by one and with replacement. Set $X_0=0$, and for each $j\geq 1$, let $X_j$ denote the number of fluorophores detected immediately following the $j^{\text{th}}$ sampled particle. The transition probabilites don't seem to difficult to evaluate. For example, $$P(X_{j+1}=2|X_j=1)=\frac{1}{100}\cdot \frac{999}{1000}$$

Comment: The $999/1000$ is the probability that the sampled particle we observed is a fluorophore that's distinct from the fluorophore we already observed and the $1/100$ is the probability that we were able to accurately detect the fluorophore. If $N=\min\{j\geq 1:X_j=1000\}$ we need to find $n$ so that $P(N\geq n)\geq 0.95$. I don't know if this procedure is appropriate considering the recent remarks made by  @saulspatz

Comment: I think it makes more sense to assume that youa re taking pictures of all the particles, and that in a single picture, we have a $.01$ chance of detecting a single good particle, independent of all the others.  Then a given particle has a $.99^n$ chance of being undetected in $n$ tries, hence a $\psi_n=1-.99^n$ chance of being detected at least once.  Now you just have a simple binomial process.

Comment: @lulu That's exactly what I had in mind.

Comment: @saulspatz  Missed your earlier comment, sorry!  Yes, we are saying the same thing.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers! I was able to find the solution! :-)